# Android Studio Could not find compile target android-33 for modules :app

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

As soon as I create a new Android Studio project using Kotlin, it gives me a lot of errors from the start:
[image]

I've set the SDK, NDK and JDK, believed to be set properly. I'm clueless of what I can do.

Can someone give me any orientation on how to fix the "Could not find compile target android-33 for modules :app" error?

Comment: Can you check the SDK Manager and see if you have SDK API 33 installed? If not, install it. If so, Gradle sync and see if it solves the problem. If the problem still persists, invalidate caches (tick all the boxes) and restart.

Comment: that did change a thing :/ Are there any other approaches?

Comment: Do you have the SDK 33 installed or not?

Comment: yep I do, API Level from 29 til 34

Comment: Can you create the project again from scratch and share the exact procedure you're following?

Comment: New Project -> Empty Views Activity -> Language: Kotlin -> Minimum SDK: 29 -> Build configuration: Kotlin DSL //

A Proxy Settings prompt shows up -> Enable HTTPS Proxy and I leave the form empty //

Project shows up, loads and throws Could not find compile target android-33 for modules :app